# Projection not changing in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have an ArcGIS 10.5 map document and I am trying to change the projection of it to be Albers Equal Area Conic.  The steps that I have taken are that I have taken all of the shapefiles, used the define projection tool to define each one as Albers Equal Area Conic, and then projected them using the project tool.  I also checked the data frame properties and changed them to be Albers Equal Area Conic.  I check the properties on the new shapefiles and for some reason, when displayed in ArcMap, they don't show an Albers Equal Area Conic projection even though that's what their properties say and that's what the data frame properties say.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't run Define projection on your files, just Project.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created three accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Like [@HDunn said](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330052/projection-wont-change-in-arcmap#comment538259_330052), just use Project on your layers. Define should be used when your data is an unknown coordinate system that you need to describe.

Comment: Define Projection may also be needed when the coordinate values stored in a feature class do not match the coordinate system that has been applied to it.